# Changing the app name text next to "Run" button in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am trying to change the text next to the run button. I have changed the app name by changing bundle identifier and also the project name. But I am not able to change the text near run button. You can find an image showing the text I state.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a much more difficult process than it should be.

To change the name in the toolbar, you need to change the name of your scheme.  In the menu bar, head to `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes...`  Now, select the name of the scheme that you want to change (the name that you wish to change in the toolbar).  After you have selected it, press <kbd>return</kbd> and the text will become editable.  If you change this text, it should change the name in the toolbar.

Comment: I wonder why they don't just grab this from the name of the bundle or something? Perhaps I just don't understand the concept of Scheme, but yes this seems so much more difficult than it needs to be.